# Pydantic: Field with regex param ends with AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'match'

Tags: python, regex, field, pydantic

It seems not all Field arguments are supported when used with

```
@validate_arguments
```

I am using pydantic 1.10.2

whene running this code:

```
from pydantic import validate_arguments, StrictStr, StrictInt, StrictBool, PaymentCardNumber, Field
from pydantic.typing import Annotated, Optional


@validate_arguments()
def test(a: Annotated[StrictStr, Field(regex="[a-z ]+")]):
    print(a)


test("ABCDEF")
```

then i get this:

<sub>Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\tsku1460\myPython\playground\types.py", line 12, in <module> test("ABCDEF") File "pydantic\decorator.py", line 40, in pydantic.decorator.validate_arguments.validate.wrapper_function File "pydantic\decorator.py", line 133, in pydantic.decorator.ValidatedFunction.call File "pydantic\decorator.py", line 130, in pydantic.decorator.ValidatedFunction.init_model_instance File "pydantic\main.py", line 340, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.init File "pydantic\main.py", line 1076, in pydantic.main.validate_model File "pydantic\fields.py", line 884, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate File "pydantic\fields.py", line 1101, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_singleton File "pydantic\fields.py", line 1148, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._apply_validators File "pydantic\class_validators.py", line 318, in pydantic.class_validators._generic_validator_basic.lambda13 File "pydantic\types.py", line 433, in pydantic.types.ConstrainedStr.validate AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'match'</sub>

Based on pydantic docs Field should be supported with @validate_arguments:

https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validation_decorator/#using-field-to-describe-function-arguments

Comment: Try to `import re` and then `Field(regex=re.compile("[a-z ]+"))`

Comment: This is a bug that was [fixed in 1.10.3](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/4538). Note that `1.10.3` was [yanked from PyPI](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/changelog/#v1103-2022-12-29), so you need at least `1.10.4`. But to be honest, you should just keep up with the patch versions and just upgrade to [`1.10.11`](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/1.10.11/) ASAP, if you are not ready to upgrade to v2 yet.

Comment: Pydantic was originally installed as dependeny for FastAPI (some time ago). And only now i started to use it outside of FastAPI without update. This is the reason why i had 1.10.3.  And due to FastAPI i can not update to 2.0. But I can confirm that after update to 1.10.11 working as expected.  Thank You.