# Pydantic 1.10: how to add custom validation with @validate_arguments

Tags: python, hex, pydantic

I need custom validation for HEX str in pydantic which can be used with @validate_arguments
So "1234ABCD" will be accepted but e.g. "RTYV" not.
Also "1234ABC" will be not accepted because the len is not even.

For now i created a new class and used StrictStr as a base:

```
from pydantic import StrictStr
from pydantic.typing import Union


class StrictHexStr(StrictStr):
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: Union[str]) -> Union[str]:
        value = super().validate(value)
        try:
            _ = bytes.fromhex(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("non-hexadecimal number found")
        return value
```

And now this is working as expected:

```
@validate_arguments
def test(a: StrictHexStr):
    print(a)


test("ABCDEF")
```

Is this correct approach? Or there is some other (maybe better) way to add custom validation which will work with @validate_arguments

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Field` constructor to annotate the function argument](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validation_decorator/#using-field-to-describe-function-arguments) and pass an appropriate regular expression to its `regex` parameter:

```py
from pydantic import Field, StrictStr, ValidationError, validate_arguments
from pydantic.typing import Annotated


@validate_arguments()
def test(a: Annotated[StrictStr, Field(regex="^(?:[1-9a-fA-F]{2})+$")]):
    print(a)


test("123ABC")
try:
    test("123AB")
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```
123ABC
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "a"
        ],
        "msg": "string does not match regex \"^(?:[1-9a-fA-F]{2})+$\"",
        "type": "value_error.str.regex",
        "ctx": {
            "pattern": "^(?:[1-9a-fA-F]{2})+$"
        }
    }
]
```

Note, as I mentioned in [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628323/) in my comment, that you need Pydantic version `>=1.10.4` for the `regex` parameter to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can i expand the original question? For HEX str regex with Field work totally fine. But what if you need some validation which can not be covered by Field and his params. What should be the approach here?

Comment: and one another comment regarding performance. The solution with regex is approx 20% slower that the extended type with bytes.fromhex.

Comment: @coolio Well, that was not your original question. You specifically asked about hexadecimal strings. I would say that should be asked in a separate question.