# Pydantic 1.10: how to add custom validation with @validate_arguments if options which provides Field is not sufficient

Tags: python, pydantic, typing

What is the "right" and pythonic way to add custom validation in pydantic which will work with `@validate_arguments`. There is an option to use Field for some additional rules. But what if options which provide Field is not enough.

Can I extend the pydantic types and overwrite the validate method with some custom logic? Or this approach is not recommended? Is there any other way do do it?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. You already know you _can_ provide a custom type because you [asked about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629142). You even tested its performance. You also know that regular validators are not supported because [the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validation_decorator/#config-and-validators) says so. For specific cases there are other options like I answered in that other question of yours. I am not sure what else you want here. Just do what works for you or ask about some specific problem.